# RSA encrypted 2500 bytes of data using ccrypto

Tags: ios, iphone, rsa

i saw the cryptoexcercise example on developer site and i was able to do a simple 256 bytes RSA encryption. Is it possible to scale it up to a larger data, say 2500 bytes ? if yes is it possible with the same classes ?

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/CryptoExercise/Introduction/Intro.html

how will the logic look like ? is it the typical streaming which style (cut 2500 in chunks of 256 and get the output and send it to server) or which is the recommended approach ? \
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you mean by "RSA" is asymmetric cryptography the answer is that is not the standard usage. Generally the data is encrypted with symmetric cryptography such as AES and the key is encrypted with asymmetric cryptography.

If you wanted to actually use asymmetric cryptography to encrypt that many bytes you would have to break it up into pieces, each small enough for the asymmetric function and encrypt each chunk individually. Asymmetric encryption/decryption is very slow compared to symmetric.

Comment: i got it, it is slow, but there was a requirement to do so and later left due to CPU / Memory usage. Thanks for the answer